# Unable to connect Postgis from QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have  installed PostgreSQL and PostGIS  on my laptop (Win 7 64 bit OS). I am running QGIS 1.8.0 on my machine .

When I am trying to connect Postgis I am getting connection failed error then I tried following things :

Details:

Port :5433 User name : postgres  Password :postgres

1. I checked the pg_hba.conf file (All default settings)
2. Restart the PostgreSQL service and tried
3. I have reinstalled PostsreSQL and getting same error.
4. Tried using empty fields while connecting still getting an error. (Not sure what to put in service field..tried using postgres and postgresql)
5. My firewall is disabled.
6. The database PostgreSQL (version  9.2) is installed on my local machine also postgis (version 2.0.3-2) installed on my machine and both are for 64 bit setups.

7.Should I try lower version of Postgresql with qGIS ??

[image: Screenshot 1]  [image: screenshot 2]

Researching on Google also and found similar  bugs related to connection issue(not sure)

Comment: I have postgresql 9.1 and postgis 2.0 on Linux up and running. Maybe you really should downgrade postgresql. Check your QGIS ability to connect postgis here: host: gis-lab.info; port 5432; database: osm_shp; ssl: disable; username: guest; password: guest. Have patience - there are a lot of data. Don't know which pogtresql/gis versions there.

Comment: Have you installed postgis into your database or created it from the postgis template? If not, your connect will fail.

Comment: What does the pg_hba.conf entry for "local" say? Is it using peer, ident or md5 for authentication?

Comment: @gsherman  I have installed postgis into my data base and while installing only default option was selected

Comment: @SaultDon Its md5

Comment: Im' using QGIS 1.8 and 1.9 in Windows 7 64 bit, with Postgres 9.2 and Postgis 2.0 withou any problems.

Comment: @Sunil Thanks! This means that the postgres user must exist in the postgresql database (does by default), and you must enter the "database" password (which you can set yourself). Set the postgres password with [ALTER USER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alteruser.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it matters, but for me, Postgis 1.5 and Postgres 9.0 (x86) are talking to QGIS 1.8.0 without problems.

QGIS is still 32-bit, even on Windows 7 64-bit machines. Give the x86 version a try, and the old postgis version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply It works perfectly on my machine and wondering that this issue will be fix in upcoming 2.0 version also I am not able to find such document that will check qgis 1.8.0 and PostgreSQL compatibility.. thanks once again : )

Comment: 64-bit support is still on the wish list, because all dependent packages have to be compiled with 64-bit support. I'm glad that the 32-bit is still working ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You must confirm the database is PostGIS not PostGres

Go to pgAdmin and view your database. Open and view the DB and besides "Schemas" there will be a count of schemas available. If it says "Schemas (1)" it's probably only a PostGres DB. Inside "Schemas" there should be an entry for "topology." If there is no topology it is not a spatial database (PostGIS) and therefore will not be visible in QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will help but....

I have only just started on this but I found that "localhost" would not resolve on my PC which has similar config/versions to yours.  I replaced it with 127.0.0.1 and I got a successful connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I tried that one but it was not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently as well.  What worked for me is:

1. leaving the host field blank.  "localhost" refers to connecting to
   your local machine via IP, which I don't believe is what you want.
2. look in your postgresql.conf file for

   ```
   listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
   ```

   and make sure that it is an '*', this will ensure it can find your local connection
3. check your [pg_hba.conf file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and make sure your authentication permissions are set correctly for the "local" entry

Edit:  Here's a link to my [similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36740/qgis-postgis-authentication-failure-with-trust-option) on Database Administrators.

Comment: I tried your way but it not worked : (

Comment: thanks for the link. I will look into it still wondering why it was not connecting..BTW I have resolved problem by installing 32 bit software as per @Andre Joost answer.. thanks for providing additional information : )

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in a post 5 years later, last revised 4 years later! I found it regarding "QGIS Ticket #930". What you MUST do: ONLY check the SAVE username & password in the dialog defining your connection. THAT'S ALL. It worked suddenly for me and I am pretty sure will do for you. My env.: Windows 7 Pro/QGIS 1.8/PostgreSQL 9.2/PostGIS 2.0.2/All of them 64 bits.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will look into it and let you know..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use the port 5433, but the standard port is 5432. Maybe control it.

Comment: Are you able to expand upon this as an answer because it looks more a comment/suggestion rather than something issued with confidence.

Comment: @PolyGeo  Actually I tried those previously & I tried Andre Joost workaround and it works for me perfectly : ) So if possible please protect this question.

Answer (score -1):

Install the latest version and reconnect

Comment: Could you explain why this would fix the problem